If $n$ is a perfect number, and $m \mid n, m \neq n$, then $m$ is not a perfect number

Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a perfect number, and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \mid n, m \neq n$, then $m$ is not a perfect number.

What I tried:
Assume by contradiction that $m$ is a perfect number. That is, $\sigma(m)=2m$.
since $\sigma(m) < \sigma(n)$, or specifically $2m=\sigma(m) \leq \sigma(n)-n$, then $2m \leq n$.
But I don't know how to reach a contradiction from here.

Well, it's easy to prove this if you assume $n$ to be even (using Euler's classification of the even perfect numbers).  Probably a good idea to start there, though you'll need a different argument to cover the (possibly non existent) odd case.

you're correct. question is similar
